# Automatically Taking a Screenshot?

Tags: objective-c, warnings, cocos2d-iphone, screenshot

I'm developing using the cocos2d framework, Obj-C. I have a whole method for taking a screenshot called "screenshot". I'd like to know how I can take a screenshot. I've been told to just call `[self screenshot];` but I get the warning 'GameOver' (class) may not respond to '-screenshot'. The screenshot method is in the AppDelegate.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Include the header for the application delegate and call.

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] screenshot]
```

Comment: It says no -screenshot method found for some reason. I'm not sure why, because I have a method called - (UIImage *)screenshot;

Comment: If you mean the line you gave me [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] screenshot]

Comment: I've already put that in, and that line is giving me the warning no screenshot method found

Comment: Is the -screenshot method also declared in the header of the app delegate?

Comment: Ahh, that was the problem. But now still have the warning '-screenshot' not found in protocol for the line [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] screenshot]; and for the line [self screenshot]; 'GameOver' may not respond to -'screenshot'.

Comment: Hi blindJesse and @Joethemonkey101 does this work in OSX desktop as well?